# selectInput height smaller than default

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to adjust height of a selectInput widget.

Command I usually encountered while googling was to adjust .selectize:

```
.selectize-input { line-height: 40px; }
```

[image]

while this works fine if I want the widget bigger than default, making it slimmer doesn't work in this way, ie

```
.selectize-input { line-height: 5px; }
```

will leave me with default height:

[image].

Finally, I should remark that it does work for dropdown list *(.selectize-dropdown)*, but for the box itself not.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to work with `max-height` instead? So something like `.selectize-input { max-height: 10px; overflow-y: auto; }` ?

Comment: Yes, I have, unfortunately this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to change the minimum-height.

With those 2 arguments, it should work:

```
.selectize-input {
  line-height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

and you can also adjust the paddings:

```
.selectize-input {
  line-height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```